# Why is Posts page selected when showing single Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, navigation

In Settings-Reading I have selected a static page from my "Front page displays". My Front page is "Home" and my Posts page is "News".

I have also added a Custom Post Type called "Project" without an archive or a slug and I have added a page "Projects" which uses the template `projects.php`.

So far so good, all is working, except one thing.

When I visit a single Project (CPT), in my top navigation "News" becomes selected. In the body-tag it gets the class `single single-project postid-114 single-format-standard logged-in`

And in the nav-menu News has a class of `page_item page-item-6 current_page_parent`.

I don't understand why this (News getting the `current_page_parent`-class) would be happening, as I expected that none of the page_items would become selected.

Two questions:

1. How can I get rid of this?
2. And ideally, how can I make it so that "Projects" becomes selected?

Below a screenshot to (hopefully) clarify things.

[image]

Comment: forgot to mention that it is a non-hierarchical post type & large image via: https://img.skitch.com/20110623-8gs8e2cx6eeb2qgata5mn8s7j.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be worth looking at the Codex for registering a post type, the rewrite rule should help:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

> **rewrite** (boolean or array) (optional) Rewrite permalinks with
>   this format. False to prevent rewrite.
>   Default: true and use post type as
>   slug $args array 'slug' - prepend
>   posts with this slug - defaults to
>   post type's name - use
>   array('slug'=>$slug) to customize
>   permastruct 'with_front' - allowing
>   permalinks to be prepended with front
>   base (example: if your permalink
>   structure is /blog/, then your links
>   will be: false->/news/,
>   true->/blog/news/) - defaults to true
>   'feeds' - default to has_archive value
>   'pages' - defaults to true

You probably want to set with_front to false.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I probably totally messed up here, I should indeed do something with it, otherwise I end up with the default values. Don't know what I was thinking!